# Display rows where foreign key is present in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have two tables. The first table is called Capability:
[image: Capability Table]

The second table is called Information Group:
[image: Information Group]

Some `ID`'s in the Capability table have been referenced in the Information Group table (i.e. in the Capability *column*)

At present, the query that powers the dashboard for the Capability view is:

`= Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="Capability"]}[Data]`

**I want to show only rows in the Capability table where there is at least one reference in the Information Group table.**

In other words, since Capability `ID` 10 is not referenced in Information Group, the Capability table should exclude that row in the output (i.e. shows only 1 to 9).
[image: Desired output]

|------------------------------------------------------------------|

Effort made so far:

I have managed to select distinct Capability `ID`'s in the Information Group table via this query:
`= Table.SelectColumns(Table.Distinct(Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="Information_Group"]}[Data], "Capability"), "Capability")`, which produces this:

[image: Output]

The next step that I would like to do is to check the `ID` column of the Capability table against the list above and display only rows where the values are contained in the table. Something like this:

`= Table.SelectRows(Table.Contains(Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="Capability"]}[Data], each[ID] is contained in the list))`

I have read up MSDN on using `Table.Contains`, but I cannot bridge the gap to get to where I want.

Please let me know if clarification is needed. Thank you.

[Edit]
Answer that I am satisfied with:

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("server\database", "Mclaren"),
    dbo_Capability = Table.NestedJoin(
        Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="Capability"]}[Data],{"ID"},
        Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="Information_Group"]}[Data],{"Capability"},        
        "NewColumn",
        JoinKind.RightOuter
    ),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(dbo_Capability,{"NewColumn"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to perform a merge of your "Capability"-table on "ID" with the "Information Group"-table on "Capability" with JoinKind.Inner: http://radacad.com/how-to-change-joining-types-in-power-bi-and-power-query
This acts as a filter.

Answer (score 0):

A way to achieve so in DAX is to create a table using `FILTER` and `CONTAINS`:

```
Filtered Capability = 
FILTER(
    Capability,
    CONTAINS(
        'Information Group',
        'Information Group'[Capability],
        Capability[ID]
    )
)
```

Or with a even simpler syntax using `IN` which is introduced since [Nov 2016](http://www.sqlbi.com/articles/the-in-operator-in-dax/):

```
Filtered Capability = 
FILTER(
    Capability,
    Capability[ID] IN VALUES('Information Group'[Capability])
)
```

Result will be as follows:

[image: dax]
[image: result]

Comment: Hi Foxan. Sorry I am quite new to DAX. Something like what I have posted under the edit of my original post?

Comment: @taylorswiftfan Nope. DAX is another functional language and building block in Power BI besides Power Query. It is a must learn and very powerful. You can find a tutorial here: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/guided-learning/powerbi-learning-7-1-intro-to-dax/