# Query not supported in DirectQuery (PowerBI / PowerQuery)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

A follow up from [Display rows where foreign key is present in PowerBI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42498084/display-rows-where-foreign-key-is-present-in-powerbi/42519189)

I now have the following query that retrieves data via a join and display as a table:

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("server\database", "Mclaren"),
    dbo_Capability = Table.NestedJoin(
        Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="Capability"]}[Data],{"ID"},
        Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="Information_Group"]}[Data],{"Capability"},        
        "NewColumn",
        JoinKind.RightOuter
    ),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(dbo_Capability,{"NewColumn"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Output:
[image: Output]

As it is, data is being fetched via DirectQuery to enable live data to be displayed. However, Query Editor has thrown a warning message, saying "This step results in a query that is not supported in DirectQuery mode". Having googled up, I found that the questions and answers are unique on a case-by-case basis.

The issue is resolved by switching to "Import" mode, but I would prefer not to go down that path; I would rather change the query to allow what I want to do to still happen while playing fine with DirectQuery.

Thank you.

Comment: If you provide us with a [mcve] it would be much easier and more pleasant to help. Could you please edit the question and include some DDL and DML to minimally reproduce the issue?

Comment: What type are both objects, *Information_Group* and *Capability*?

Comment: Also, why do you remove resulting "NewColumn"?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the cause of the problem is `RightJoin`. 
PowerBI doesn't support Direct Query for any types of join **other than Left Join**.

Try following:

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("server\database", "Mclaren"),
    dbo_Capability = Table.NestedJoin(
        Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="Information_Group"]}[Data],{"Capability"},        
        Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="Capability"]}[Data],{"ID"},
        "NewColumn",
        JoinKind.LeftOuter
    ),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(dbo_Capability,{"NewColumn"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Again, I see no reason in removing "NewColumn".

If both tables have no same columns, you may also find useful this approach:

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("server\database", "Mclaren"),
    dbo_Capability = Table.Join(
        Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="Information_Group"]}[Data],{"Capability"},        
        Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="Capability"]}[Data],{"ID"},
        JoinKind.LeftOuter
    )
in
    dbo_Capability
```

The resulting table will be same as using `LEFT JOIN` in SQL.